# Store nodeid when migrating from mercurial to git

Tags: git, mercurial

I have a huge hg project, and my documents use the unique hg hash (nodeid) to specify revisions on the repository.

I want to convert the repo to git, with it's history. **And I want to be able to search the original hg nodeids on the history, in the new git repo.** (I think the best way will be adding it to the commit message in git).

How can I do that? Is there a conversion tool that'll do that automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[git-remote-hg](https://github.com/felipec/git-remote-hg) allows to preserve Mercurial revisions as Git commit notes:

```
git config core.notesRef refs/notes/hg
```

Set it before conversion.

Comment: This is, I think, the simplest and probably best method (upvoted). If the OP really wants the hash IDs directly in the Git commit text, though, it's probably not hard to tweak many of the various converters using `fast-import` to insert the Mercurial hash ID directly.

Comment: It's (almost) working. To use `git config` command, I should create the git repo first (`git init`), and if I do so, the conversion command fails:`fatal: destination path 'xxx' already exists and is not an empty directory.`. I used `git config --global core.notesRef refs/notes/hg` and converted my hg repo without creating git repo first, and it's working. Tnx.

Comment: Two additions : 1. In order to fetch the notes after clone: `git fetch origin refs/notes/*:refs/notes/*`, otherwise notes won't be cloned. 2. In order to convert  the nodeid notes to commit messages : `git filter-branch --msg-filter 'cat && printf "created from hg nodeid:" && git show --notes=hg --format=%N $GIT_COMMIT --no-patch || true'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use revision in a form `:/<id>` to refer to a commit with string `<id>` in message. it can be used for checkout or just `git show`. It is quite slow as it should make a full search, and it's not stable if several commits matches it, but otherwise quite usable.

[See description from docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#gitrevisions-emlttextgtemegemfixnastybugem)